# How to group two rows in a column based on a second in Python?

Tags: python

I have a data-frame like below and I want to group data based on second column. The table is unique on ColumnA.

Condition:

If a value in columnA appears in any row in columnB, add that value to the value from columnA corresponding to the value in columnB.

Input:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB12 | CD34 | 30 |
| CD34 | NULL | 40 |

Output:

| ColumnA | Values |
| --- | --- |
| AB12 | 70 |

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What library or framework are you looking (or allowed) to use?

Comment: Please include sample(s) in text form that we can copy and paste for helping you, we don't want to type everything in... check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I have not been able to formulate it with pandas yet, but my thought process in sql was to create something like this: SELECT t1.ColumnA,  COALESCE(t1.ColumnB, t2.ColumnA) as columnC FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t2 ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnB;